# I am getting errors from unknown elements

Tags: angular

on an Angular project, I set up routing and I organized my project into modules.

I've been on it for 3 days, yet I think I did the job well but I still have an unknown component error.

I'm joining my project on stackblitz, hoping you can help me
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-acfk6e?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed your issues in here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-w9bq4c

Since it's specific case, I don't have a way to show the code in here. But I think the issue has a common pattern and is quite common.

Let's say you have the following structure:

> - AppModule
>
>   - PartialsModule
>
>     - PageCartModule
>     - PageProductsModule
>   - ProductModule
>
>     - ... Components

While you have created `PageProductsModule` and its components (like `ProductAddRemoveComponent` which threw an error), but it was never used by the main module. You could actually write anything in `product-add-remove` folder *(anything means including invalid syntax)* and would not get an error about invalid syntax. First it should be included in your main module and then you should also check if you included modules correctly (I like to test by writing some nonsense in `.ts` files so that I would know Angular detects them correctly).

So, what I did was:

In `AppModule` (the main one) `imports` field added `PartialsModule` which is next by level. `PartialsModule` itself has children modules (like `PageProductModule`).

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your reply. it helped me to move forward

**it works**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule,  } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { PartialsModule } from './pages/partials/partials.module';

// -------------   bloc import is required ------------
import { PageCartModule } from './pages/page-cart/page-cart.module';
import { PageProductModule } from './pages/page-product/page-product.module';
import { PageProductsModule } from './pages/page-products/page-products.module';
// -----------------------------------------------------

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, ],
  imports: [BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule, PartialsModule, ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**it does not work**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule,  } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { PartialsModule } from './pages/partials/partials.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, ],
  imports: [BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule, PartialsModule, ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I don't understand why just putting the imports makes it work perfectly without errors.
why ?

you can see on stackblitz:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jocphb?